# React Hooks: Prevent Concurrent GET Requests in useEffect with isFetching

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am currently developing a feature in React where I need to execute a GET request upon every change to `mapState.bounds`, a value I extract from my feature's slice using Redux's useSelector. Here is a simplified version of my current implementation:

```js
const mapState = useSelector(selectMapState); 
const [searchFoo, { data, isFetching }] = useLazyGetFooSearchQuery();

const fetchData = React.useCallback(async (searchQuery: string) => {
    const { isError, error } = await searchFoo({ query: searchQuery });

    if (isError) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}, [searchFoo]);
    
React.useEffect(() => {
    /*
        Abort if already fetching to prevent 
        executing concurrent GET queries
    */
    if (isFetching) return;

    const searchQuery = JSON.stringify({/* A query based on mapState.bounds */ });

    fetchData(searchQuery).catch((error) => console.error(error));
}, [
    mapState.bounds,
    /* 
       This causes an infinite loop, but not including it 
       in the dependency array will break the exhaustive deps rule
    */
    isFetching,
    fetchData,
]);
```

The main goal is to avoid executing concurrent GET queries when mapState.bounds changes in quick succession. The current setup does work when I exclude isFetching from the dependency array in useEffect, but this goes against React's guidelines of maintaining exhaustive dependency arrays. Including it as a dependency results in an infinite loop:

1. The value of `mapState.bounds` changes
2. `useEffect` is fired
3. `fetchData` is called asynchronously
4. `isFetching` is changed to `true` by redux-toolkit
5. `useEffect` is fired, but returns immediately
6. `data` is populated, `fetchData` returns void
7. `isFetching` changes to `false`
8. `useEffect` is fired again because of the previous step - goto step 3

A possible solution could be executing the fetch query within an event listener's callback, say onBoundsChange, but I am interested in knowing if there's a way to achieve it using React hooks while keeping all the variables used in the hook inside the dependency array, as officially recommended.

How could I leverage React hooks to prevent concurrent GET queries while adhering to the exhaustive dependency rule?

Comment: What about checking isFetching inside the fetchData callback? The changes to it will cause useCallback to generate a new function on each render, but won't actually start fetching data.

Comment: @RobertNubel That's a good suggestion but I've already tried it. Implementing this would require including isFetching in the dependency array of the useCallback hook. This, in turn, prompts fetchData to be redefined twice: once when the GET query is initiated (isFetching = true), and once after it's finished (isFetching = false).
This series of events triggers useEffect twice due to the presence of fetchData in its dependency array. During the second execution of useEffect, it would initiate the same infinite loop because the value of isFetching would be false, so fetchData wouldn't abort.

Comment: Yeah, true. I think what _would_ work is to use a ref, e.g. `refIsFetching`, and keep it updated with something like `useEffect(() => refIsFetching.current = IsFetching, [IsFetching]`. Then, your data-fetching `useEffect` hook can check the ref value without specifying it as a dependency.

Comment: @RobertNubel That's a good idea! I'll try it tomorrow and report back with the results.

Comment: @DrewReese The idea is to fetch `Foo` every time the user moves or zooms the map, which is rendered in a different component. Additionally, it should be fetched when the user changes the map's settings. All these changes are reflected in the feature's Redux state. In the main component (the one in the example), I'm using useEffect to detect those changes by including them in the dependency array and manually triggering fetch when they occur. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it's possible to achieve the same functionality with a standard toolkit query and the skip option.

Comment: I think you could since it appears the query is derived from the `mapState.bounds` value from what I can tell. What is the value of `mapState.bounds`? Is it a new object reference each time the component renders? You should look to memoize your dependencies so they aren't triggering render loops.

Comment: @DrewReese In the actual implementation, it's an array of { lat: number, lng: number } objects. However, in the dependency array, I'm stringifying it like this: `[ JSON.stringify(mapState.bounds), isFetching, fetchData]`. The purpose of this is to ensure that the hook is fired only when at least one value within the array changes, and not when the array reference is changed. Thanks to that, there are no render loops - every value in the dependency array is primitive. For simplicity's sake, I decided not to include the stringify call in my example.

Comment: @DrewReese Tomorrow, I'll try experimenting with skip tokens to see if it's possible to use them instead of the useEffect hook, considering the context of my project. If it doesn't work out, I'll update my question and explain what I tried and why it didn't work, thanks!

Comment: I'd also suggest throttling/debouncing the `fetchData` or `searchFoo` functions if the issue is really just that they are called too often. This wouldn't necessarily eliminate any request concurrency issue, but you should probably be using abort tokens anyway to kill in-flight requests when another request is needed.